cmake does not inherit INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES from INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  hello_test.cc
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test PUBLIC
  GTest::gtest_main
)

# 1. This verifies that GTest::gtest_main is STATIC_LIBRARY
get_target_property(TARGET_TYPE GTest::gtest_main TYPE)
if(TARGET_TYPE)
    message(STATUS "Target type for hello_test: ${TARGET_TYPE}")
else()
    message(STATUS "Target type for hello_test is not set.")
endif()

# target_include_directories(
#   hello_test
#   PRIVATE ${googletest_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/include  # Directly include the path from the googletest source
# )

# Retrieve the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property
get_target_property(INTERFACE_DIRS GTest::gtest_main  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

# 2. This verifies that INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of GTest::gtest_main is correctly set
if(INTERFACE_DIRS)
    message(STATUS "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for GTest::gtest_main: ${INTERFACE_DIRS}")
else()
    message(STATUS "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for GTest::gtest_main is not set or empty.")
endif()   

# Retrieve the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property
get_target_property(DIR hello_test  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

# 3. this prints empty value. Why? should it inherit INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES from GTest::gtest_main?
if(DIR)
    message(STATUS "INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for hello_test: ${DIR}")
else()
    message(STATUS "INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for hello_test is not set or empty.")
endif() 

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)

Above code prints:
-- Target type for hello_test: STATIC_LIBRARY
-- INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for GTest::gtest_main: $<BUILD_INTERFACE:/home/shan/work/phisar/tmp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include$<SEMICOLON>/home/shan/work/phisar/tmp/build/_deps/googletest-src/googletest>;$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/include>
-- INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for hello_test is not set or empty.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/shan/work/phisar/tmp/build

My question is why hello_test  target not inherit include dirs from GTest::gtest_main ?   More interestingly, the code compiles. This code is directly from https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html, i ask this question because i encounter a situation that <gtest/gtest.h> header files not found error with gtest, and the cmake is the same above. I do not know why the example in official webpage works. and the printing result also i can not understand. There must some misunderstanding for me.
